# Output the contents of an ETS Table Erlang

Tags: erlang, tuples, ets, ordered-set

I am new to the world of Erlang so I am trying to experiment with it.

I have an ETS table that is called numbers.

```
ets:new(numbers,[ordered_set,named_table])
```

It has the format [{Name,Number},{Name,Number}] etc.

I am wondering is there a way to output the contents of the whole the ets table?

Comment: for this case (get the whole content) `ets:tab2list(numbers)` does the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Tl;dr

you can use

```
ets:match_object(Tab, {'$0', '$1'}).
```

Where `Tab` is your table name, i.e. `numbers`.

## In depth:

The second argument is a [match pattern](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#match_object-2), leaving "free variables" `'$0'` and `'$1'`.

Let's say you inserted:

```
> ets:insert(Tab, [{age, 45}, {length, 10}, {height, 45}]).
```

You could get out all `{_, 45}` tuples with:

```
> ets:match_object(Tab, {'$0', 45}). 
[{age, 45}, {height, 45}]
```

By making all (in this case, 2) of the tuple parameters free variables, you will match everything in the table.

I highly recommend reading [Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/ets) for more info!